# How to Parse Text File delimited with ~ into a Datatable or Array in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, parsing, multidimensional-array, datatable, text-files

I'm trying to parse the text file into an array or datatable where Lines Starting with D, O, and L are a single Row of data.

There are never more than 1 "L" Lines.

I want to get this into a datatable or 2-dimensional array where the column header names (locations) are

- Date {D3}
- Customer Name {O2}
- Address {O3}
- City {O7}
- State {O8}
- Zipcode {O9}
- Reference ID {D17}
- Amount {D20}

I tried

```
TextFieldParser("C:\Users\MyAccount\test.txt")
FileReader.SetDelimiters("~")
```

But I'm not understanding how to work with the output. Any ideas?

```
B~AAA~~12/03/19~12/03/19~1~428.51~APV~REF~K8~~
D~AAA~~12/03/19~12/03/19~APV~REF~N~REFUNDCIS~~12/03/19~0~N~N~Y~~~0000244909~~~72.90~~~00~N~0~12/03/19~0~12/03/19~12/03/19~0~K8~~~N~N~0~
O~JOHN DOE~ 1000 NOAKY LN   ~~~~DETROIT~MI~31000~~~
L~01~141011~000~00000~000~00~000~~REFUND0000244909JOHN DOE~72.90~N~N~~~N~
D~AAA~~12/03/19~12/03/19~APV~REF~N~REFUNDCIS~~12/03/19~0~N~N~Y~~~0000404236~~~101.42~~~00~N~0~12/03/19~0~12/03/19~12/03/19~0~K8~~~N~N~0~
O~BRUCE DOE~UNIT 1 1000 E MICHIGAN AVE   ~~~~DETROIT~MI~31000~~~
L~01~141011~000~00000~000~00~000~~REFUND0000404236BRUCE DOE~101.42~N~N~~~N~
D~AAA~~12/03/19~12/03/19~APV~REF~N~REFUNDCIS~~12/03/19~0~N~N~Y~~~0000436750~~~180.00~~~00~N~0~12/03/19~0~12/03/19~12/03/19~0~K8~~~N~N~0~
O~JOEL DOE~ 100 MICHIGAN AVE   ~~~~DETROIT~MI~31000~~~
L~01~141011~000~00000~000~00~000~~REFUND0000436750JOEL DOE~180.00~N~N~~~N~
D~AAA~~12/03/19~12/03/19~APV~REF~N~REFUNDCIS~~12/03/19~0~N~N~Y~~~0000448122~~~74.19~~~00~N~0~12/03/19~0~12/03/19~12/03/19~0~K8~~~N~N~0~
O~JOHN DOE~ 100 MICHIGAN AVE   ~~~~DETROIT~MI~31000~~~
L~01~141011~000~00000~000~00~000~~REFUND0000448122JOHN DOE~74.19~N~N~~~N~
```

Comment: The documentation for that class has a code example. I suggest that you read it, follow it and edit it as required.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?  `TextFieldParser` is documented in MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I took the code from MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netcore-3.1
I needed to know how many columns I needed in the datatable.

```
Private Sub OpCode1()
    Dim maxColumnCount As Integer
    Using MyReader As New TextFieldParser("C:\Users\xxx\test.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = {"~"}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
        'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                ' Include code here to handle the row.
                If currentRow.Count > maxColumnCount Then
                    maxColumnCount = currentRow.Count
                End If
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show(maxColumnCount.ToString)
End Sub
```

Once I had the number of columns needed, I created a `DataTable` and added the necessary number of columns. Then, where the Example instructed you to handle the row, I added the row to the `DataTable`. Lastly, I displayed the `DataTable` in a `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub OPCode()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    For i = 1 To 38
        dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString)
    Next

    Using MyReader As New TextFieldParser("C:\Users\xxx\test.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = {"~"}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
        'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                ' Include code here to handle the row.

                dt.Rows.Add(currentRow)

            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

More specific to your data...

```
Private Sub OpCode()

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
    dt.Columns.Add("Customer Name", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Address", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("City", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("State", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Zipcode", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("RefID", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Decimal))

    Dim DataDate As Date
    Dim RefID As String = ""
    Dim Amount As Decimal

    Using MyReader As New TextFieldParser("C:\Users\maryo\test.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = {"~"}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
        'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                ' Include code here to handle the row.
                If currentRow(0) = "D" Then
                    DataDate = CDate(currentRow(3))
                    RefID = currentRow(17)
                    Amount = CDec(currentRow(20))
                End If
                If currentRow(0) = "O" Then
                    dt.Rows.Add({DataDate, currentRow(1), currentRow(2), currentRow(6), currentRow(7), currentRow(8), RefID, Amount})
                End If
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

I assumed that the D row applies to the following O row. I saved the data from the D row in the 3 variables and used it when the next row is read.

Remember collections (including arrays) are zero based in .net.